# jquery serializeArray form a disabled form

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create an xml string from all of my form inputs, it works only if the form is enabled. how can i create the xml when all of the form inputs are disabled?

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Disabled form controls are not submitted when the form is submitted. You could do this:

1. Create a submit handler for the form.
2. Inside the submit handler, create a clone of the form.
3. Un-disable all of the form controls in the clone.
4. AJAX submit using the serialized data from the clone.
5. When the AJAX call returns, load whatever page you would have loaded in the originial submit.

Don't forget to return false at the end of the submit handler.

Comment: I changed it, so i wont use serialized array function , i loop through all the inputs instead. thank's any way.